# Question about part (ii) of Archimedean Property in Stephen Abbott's Book

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have been self-studying analysis using Abbott's Book. In p.19, the Archimedean Property has two parts

> (i) Given any number $x\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n>x$.
>
> (ii) Given any real number $y > 0$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $1/n < y$

Then a proof of (i) is given and I can follow it. What I don't understand is the subsequent statement:

> Part (ii) follows from (i) by letting $x = 1/y$.

If we simply substitute $x = 1/y$ to (i), we get

> Given any number $1/y\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n>1/y$.

But this does not seem to be equivalent to (ii). I have trouble seeing how we can obtain (ii) from (i) by letting $x=1/y$.

As an aside, whenever I couldn't figure out something like this during self-learning on a maths topic, should I spend a lot of time pondering, or continue reading, or just ask online/others? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of your final inequality by the positive term $\frac yn$

Comment: But this would give us "Given any number $1/y\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $1/n<y$" which is not exactly the same as (ii). Am I missing something?

Comment: @artils1997 Well you need $y\gt 0$ for the multiplication to be justified without reversing the inequality. So that condition comes in. And since $\frac 1/y$ is positive precisely when $y$ is positive, you can choose $y$ arbitrarily as a positive real number (because $\frac 1y$ is arbitrary)